# Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have recently installed Laravel 5 via Composer. I tried creating a new controller using Artisan and got the following error. Am I missing something?

> bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php. Failed to open stream: No such file or directory. The "vendor" folder does not exist.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Turns out I didn't enable openssl in my php.ini so when I created my new project with composer it was installed from source. I changed that and ran

```
composer update
```

now the vendor folder was created.

Answer (score 336):

Run composer with --no-scripts

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

This shall fix the issue. I tried this on Mac and Linux.

Comment: Sometimes when you run: "composer install" you got that error too,  so the best option is first run:  "composer install --no-scripts" and then run composer install normally.

Comment: Composer documentation: --no-scripts: Skips execution of scripts defined in composer.json. (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update)

Comment: It's much better to use composer install, because it will run everything necessary to install all dependencies, including scripts.

Comment: error  Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\composer
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: `composer install` was not working for me, `composer update --no-scripts` did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Please Now I get: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. After Run the command composer update --no-scripts. Also it tooks a lot time.

Answer (score 141):

Which OS you are using ?
For Windows :
Go to `Command Prompt`

**set path to `www/{ur project}`**

For me : `www/laravel5`

Then type this command :  **`composer install`**

It will automatically install all dependency in `vendor/`

Answer (score 103):

Run `composer install` in your root project folder (or `php composer.phar install`).

Answer (score 58):

Did you create a new project or did you clone an existing project?

If you cloned an existing project it's very important to run

```
composer install
```

That way all the dependencies that are missing will be installed.

But if you create a new project you should run this command to make a new project using composer

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel name-of-your-project
```

Answer (score 24):

I encountered the same problem. It occurred because composer was not able to install the dependencies specified in composer.json file.
try running

```
composer install
```

If this does not solve the problem, make sure
the following php modules are installed
php-mbstring
php-dom

To install this extensions run the following in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php-dom
```

once the installation is complete

try running the command in your project root folder

```
composer install
```

Comment: I installed php-xml to get this working rather than php-dom (which doesn't exist in 16.04).

Comment: Great!!! It worked!!

Installing php-xml instead of php-dom is default action for apt-get in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: it worked after installing mbstring and php-dom. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

You need to regenerate `autoload.php` file. you can use `dump-autoload` to do that without having to go through an install or update.

use

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to generate `autoload.php` file again in `/vendor` directory.

Comment: This Works for me but having this error Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found.

Answer (score 21):

Following this below step solved my problem. You may try

```
composer update --no-scripts 
composer update
```

Answer (score 20):

Just run this inside the directory where you installed your project

```
composer install
```

Comment: I did this and it worked, but why? I'd like to understand the reason please.

Comment: @SimonSuh for some reason (network failure, new project was created without going through all commands, error during manual install, custom build install...) composer dependencies where no installed or are not up to date. this command will install and update all dependencies of  your project and that will fix the issue. hope it is enought

Answer (score 20):

After checking `php` version and a lot of research , the problem was on `Composer` side so just run the following command

**`composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`**

Answer (score 8):

This solution worked for me. The reason is not to have a **vendor folder** in your application.

Follow these steps:

1. if your project has `composer.json` file, delete it
2. then run

   ```
   composer require phpspec/phpspec
   ```

That command add vendor folder to your project

Answer (score 7):

go to your project folder via cmd. run the following command

```
composer update
```

it will install the missing vendor folder and files in your project.

but in some cases, it gives an error like "Your configuration does not allow connection to ....." in cmd.

for that go to your **composer.json** file,

change `"secure-http": true` to `"secure-http": false`

but in some cases (as was in my case) you may not find such line in your file. for that do the following action:

```
change "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

to

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "secure-http": false
}
```

and run again `composer update` command.

hope this will solve problem.

Answer (score 6):

Just run the following commands,

```
composer update
```

Or

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 6):

When the new project created the laravel require to load vendors to autoload the libraries , 
We use composer update to

```
composer update
```

Composer is a  dependency manager allows you to delegate responsibility for managing your dependencies to a third party.

Answer (score 5):

Just setup a new project using `composer` instead of `laravel` like this:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myProje
```

Answer (score 5):

Delete **Vendor** then `composer install`

Answer (score 3):

I also had that error. But none of the above solved the issue. So i uninstalled and again installed the composer. Then i did `composer update`. and the problem was fixed.

Comment: after ````composer install````

Answer (score 3):

You are missing vendor folder, probably its new cloned repository or new project

the vendor folder is populated by composer binary which reads composer.json file or system requirements and installs packaged under vendor folder and create an autoload script that has all classed

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you carry out the following instructions you need to make sure you have composer installed globally on your machine;
Open you Mac terminal and run the following command:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

once composer is installed globally run the following command after you are in the directory of the project:

```
composer install
```

once completed in it update and install all the required packages.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem with laravel and artisan, the solution:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 2):

We got an error because we have missing *vendor* folder in our project, The vendor directory contains our Composer dependencies.

Need `/vendor` folder because all packages are there and including all the classes Laravel uses, A problem can be solved after following just two steps:

```
composer update --no-scripts 
composer update
```

- **--no-scripts**: Skips execution of scripts defined in `composer.json`
- **composer update**: This will check for newer versions of the libraries you required in your project. If a newer version is found and it's compatible with the version constraint defined in the `composer.json` file, it will replace the previous version installed. The `composer.lock` file will be updated to reflect these changes.

These two commands, we will Recreate the vendor folder in our project and after that our project will be working smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I got this when I did `composer update` instead of `composer install`.

Answer (score 1):

I added `composer.lock` file to .gitignore, after commit that file to repository error is gone :)

Answer (score 1):

my problem is solved by

```
composer update
composer install
php artisan key:generate
```

if you any other problem you can clear cache and config
Clear Route cache:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Clear View cache:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Clear Config cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Something I realise is your composer.json file will have some sort of script like

```
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
```

what works for me:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
```

removing `post install cmd` helped running composer install without any issue.

Hope this helps

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Delete vendor folder and run composer install command. It is working 100%

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to enable another extension, namely `php_mbstring.dll` in the `php.ini` file before it could work. It's listed under `extension=php_mbstring.dll`. Find it in the `php.ini` file and remove the semi-colon (`;`) in front of it and save the file.

After this run `install composer` again in the root directory of your Laravel applcication and is should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows user you may uninstall Composer. Then install Composer. After that you install Laravel. Maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:
after installing the project, I open the project's folder and run these two commands

```
composer update

composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am relevant -

I have downloaded the Github release of laravel and installed with lando, and failed to start it.

In lando recipe, I had to add `php: 8.1` in `.lando.yml`

```yaml
name: ltest1
recipe: laravel
config:
  webroot: public
  php: 8.1
```

and

```bash
$ lando ssh
$ composer install
$ php artisan key:generate
```