# Whoops, looks like something went wrong. error in Laravel 5 when trying to run on built in server

Tags: php, git, laravel-5.1

I cloned a project from my git repo and tried to do following command

```
php artisan serve
```

I was getting

```
Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php
```

So I followed this answer

[Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php)

and then did `composer install`

after this when I did

```
php artisan serve
```

The server started fine but in chrome browser I am getting following error

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong. error in Laravel 5
```

Any heads Up what could have gone wrong

**UPDATE**

I opened the folder storage/logs/ and there is a file called `laravel`
this is the dump from it

```
`[2015-11-18 10:48:25] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php:6943
Stack trace:
#0 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1242): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#1 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#3 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1287): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#4 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1271): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1257): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#7 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#8 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(9459): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Middle...')
#9 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2932): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(9459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(9449): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2209): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2192): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 D:\iclock.in\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 D:\iclock.in\server.php(21): require_once('D:\\iclock.in\\pu...')
#18 {main}  
[2015-11-18 10:48:25] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php:6943
Stack trace:
#0 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1242): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#1 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#3 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1287): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#4 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1271): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1257): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#7 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#8 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2216): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Middle...')
#9 D:\iclock.in\public\index.php(58): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Http\Response))
#10 D:\iclock.in\server.php(21): require_once('D:\\iclock.in\\pu...')
#11 {main}  
[2015-11-18 10:48:32] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php:6943
Stack trace:
#0 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1242): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#1 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#3 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1287): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#4 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1271): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1257): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#7 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#8 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(9459): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Middle...')
#9 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2932): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(9459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(9449): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2209): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2192): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 D:\iclock.in\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 D:\iclock.in\server.php(21): require_once('D:\\iclock.in\\pu...')
#18 {main}  
[2015-11-18 10:48:32] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php:6943
Stack trace:
#0 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1242): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#1 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#3 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1287): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#4 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1271): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1257): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#7 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#8 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2216): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Middle...')
#9 D:\iclock.in\public\index.php(58): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Http\Response))
#10 D:\iclock.in\server.php(21): require_once('D:\\iclock.in\\pu...')
#11 {main}  
[2015-11-18 10:49:10] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php:6943
Stack trace:
#0 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1242): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#1 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#3 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1287): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#4 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1271): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1257): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#7 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#8 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(9459): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Middle...')
#9 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2932): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(9459): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(9449): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2209): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2192): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 D:\iclock.in\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 D:\iclock.in\server.php(21): require_once('D:\\iclock.in\\pu...')
#18 {main}  
[2015-11-18 10:49:10] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.' in D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php:6943
Stack trace:
#0 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1242): Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#1 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#2 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('encrypter', Array)
#3 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1287): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#4 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1271): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1257): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1195): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#7 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(1733): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Http\\Middle...', Array)
#8 D:\iclock.in\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php(2216): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Http\\Middle...')
#9 D:\iclock.in\public\index.php(58): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Http\Response))
#10 D:\iclock.in\server.php(21): require_once('D:\\iclock.in\\pu...')
#11 {main}
```

`
Thanks & Regards

Comment: Usually the error is followed by a stacktrace, maybe you could post it aswell ?

Comment: I am just getting this error , Which even I am not able to understand why is this happening ,

Comment: Take a look in the logs, these should be in `storage/logs`

Comment: @Jerodev okay I will see

Comment: @Jerodev I updated my question with the log dump

Comment: @Daan I uploaded the error dump I understand nothing outof it though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a `.env` file in the root of your project. This file contains all the global settings for your application.

Normaly there is a `.env.example` file in the root of your application. rename this file to `.env` and change the `APP_KEY` property to a random string for better security.

Comment: well I already solved it . Lot of things had to be changed including .env files : ) . Anyways I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the **.env.example** to **.env**
2. Go to *bootstrap=>app.php* and uncomment `$app->withEloquent();`
3. Make sure that `APP_DEBUG=true` in **.env** file. Now it will work.