# New Laravel Project Throwing 500 Error: require(): Failed opening required autoload.php

Tags: php, apache, laravel, openssl, lamp

I trying to learn laravel and I am attempting to set it up on my server.

I have meticulously followed all the instructions in this tutorial while changing some variables based on the names of my own directories:
http://davidmyers.name/post/laravel-on-digital-ocean

The 500 error only is thrown when I visit the laravel project's public folder. When I attempt to visit any other page such as PHPMyAdmin or any other PHP or HTML page, the page pulls up just fine.

Is there anything I could be missing that is not included in the tutorial that I referenced? I double checked that I am following all the steps correctly.

Also, running composer update in the directory throws this error:

```
 [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/testproj/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No
   such file or directory in /var/www/html/testproj/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
  PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/testproj/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include
  _path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/testproj/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

I found this related stackoverflow article:
[Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php)
but the solution did not work for me, since my phpinfo() shows that OpenSSL is enabled.

Comment: Have you run `composer install` ?  This should automatically run `php artisan optimize` after install, which I believe is the command to create the file in question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was doing everything right, but when I went to run `composer install` I didn't see that it was throwing an installation error due to my server not having enough memory. Increasing my server's memory fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the server does not have access to those locations.
 Run the following commands

```
sudo chmod 755 -R "your project name"
```

and then

```
chmod -R o+w "your project name" /storage
```

if it still doesn't work try running:

```
sudo chmod 775-R "your project name"
sudo chmod 775-R "your project name"/storage
```

or

```
sudo chmod 777-R "your project name"
sudo chmod 777-R "your project name"/storage
```

Comment: Do not use chmod 777 for your entire project. use 755. https://blackchickenhost.com/whmcs/knowledgebase/71/Why-You-Should-Never-Use-777-Permissions-Anywhere-Ever-Full-Stop-End-of-Story.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you run `composer install` ?  This should automatically run `php artisan optimize` after install, which I believe is the command to create the file in question.

Answer (score 1):

You must install dependencies by composer using:

```
composer install
```

and then give right permission to `storage` directory:

```
chmod 777 -R storage
```

or

```
sudo chmod 777 -R storage
```

Comment: Do not use chmod 777 for your entire project. use 755. https://blackchickenhost.com/whmcs/knowledgebase/71/Why-You-Should-Never-Use-777-Permissions-Anywhere-Ever-Full-Stop-End-of-Story.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to consider,
1. Web server throwing 500 error (as if text and font were from Chrome) or 
2. The application is showing 500 error (with beautiful image and text)

Case 1: you probably need to install composer

```
    sudo composer install
```

Case 2: Check appropriate permission on storage/ (as suggested on other answers) and check if you have .env file. if not copy .env.example and rename to .env and you also need to generate application key.

```
    sudo php artisan key:generate
```

PS: You may be in this situation mostly if you have used git to deploy your code on server and your development machine is different. This answer is based on the scenario which I faced and how it was solved.