# how do i use the laravel talk functionality

Tags: laravel

i want to add a user conversation function in my app, but i am having problems installing the talk functionality. i have downloaded the project from github, but i was unable to use it because of this two errors

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\tok\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tok\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\tok\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\tok\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17. is there a way out of???
```

does anyone know how use the talk functionality by nahid??

Comment: Do you use PHP 5.6>?

Comment: Run composer install in  project folder

Comment: yes @RobinDirksen i am running php 7

Comment: @channasmcs every time i run that command i get a "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." error which now cannot be undone because it only indicates two lines of Whoops, looks like something went wrong.on the screen.

Comment: try running with `composer install --no-scripts`. The whoops error is from laravel which will typically triggered from the post installation scripts. Make `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env` file and see what error description it shows

Comment: APP_DEBUG=true is enabled, still i get two lines of whoops error and nothing else on the screen

Comment: @SirGeorge did you run `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: @RobinDirksen i have two lines of whoops error. everytime i import a project from github and run composer install i get this two lines and after that it cant be reversed, it shows the two lines no matter what kind of modification you make to the files

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run the following in the project folder:

```
Composer Install
```

Here is a question with a similar issue that might help you get to the root cause: (possible duplicate question)

[Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php)

Comment: every time i run that command i get a "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." error which now cannot be undone because it only indicates two lines of Whoops, looks like something went wrong.on the screen.

Comment: Go to your .ENV file and change debug to 'True', and then refresh the page and paste the first few lines of the error here, it should tell you exactly what is going wrong

Comment: thats why i was telling you, when i try to run composer install command, i get the whoops error, and from that moment, i doesnt matter what you edit or change, it will keep showing the two lines of whoops error

Comment: i have changed it still nothing