# Laravel does not create folder vendor

Tags: php, laravel

After installing Composer it worked well, Laravel created all folders and it started correctly with:

```
php artisan serve
```

Now, when I try:

```
laravel new mypro
```

It does not create the `vendor` folder. And when I try:

```
php artisan serve
```

It says:

```
php artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[6]_PHP_Learning/Laravel_1/blog4/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[6]_PHP_Learning/Laravel_1/blog4/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[6]_PHP_Learning/Laravel_1/blog4/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[6]_PHP_Learning/Laravel_1/blog4/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

After I copy folder vendor it says:

```
php artisan serve
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider' not found in /mnt/PROJECTS/[3]_PROCOM/[6]_PHP_Learning/Laravel_1/blog3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                 
  Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider' not found
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. It occurred because the composer was not able to install the dependencies specified in composer.json file. try running

```
composer install
```

If this does not solve the problem, make sure the following PHP modules are installed php-mbstring php-dom

To install this extensions run the following in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php-dom
```

once the installation is complete

try running the command again in your project root folder

```
composer install
```

So, if the above doesn't work, you can as well try this command

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

More solutions on this thread.
[Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of copying vendor folder please run a command

```
composer install
```

in your laravel's project directory

Comment: Made it, nothing changed, it told:     composer install
Cannot create cache directory /home/satori/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/satori/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

Comment: Cannot create cache directory /home/satori/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.4.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.6].

Comment: - laravel/framework v5.4.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.

Comment: Problem 2
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 5.7.9 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.7.9].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

Comment: your directory is not writeable you don't have permission to write in it

Comment: Problem 3
    - laravel/framework v5.4.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/tinker v1.0.0 requires illuminate/console ~5.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.6].
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker v1.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v1.0.0].

Comment: To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini

Comment: - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini

Comment: - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple solutions from different sources, the only thing that worked for me was upgrading the PHP version.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install it manually  `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring`

Comment: Made it, now it says: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 5.7.9 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.7.9].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

Comment: try this now `sudo apt-get install php-xml`

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-xml is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libvpx1:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.