# Failed to open autoload file

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm trying get access to project which I cloned from github I get this errors:

```
Warning: require(H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='H:\xampp\php\PEAR') in H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

I've read some questions with same issue and all of them say to run

```
composer install
```

But when I do this I get error in my command prompt:

```
Warning: require(H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.de
v\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bo
otstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='H:\xampp\php\PEAR') in H:\xampp\h
tdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Warning:  require(H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.
php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\xampp\htdocs\schedu
le.dev\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.d
ev\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='H:\xampp\php\PEAR') in H:\xa
mpp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned wit
h error code 255
```

Comment: Remove `php artisan clear-compiled` from the `pre-update-cmd` in your composer.json.

Comment: and do composer install?

Comment: Yes. Hopefully it should work fine after that, and then you can add that line back in.

Comment: it worked but now I have another issue(
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap\app.php:14 Stack trace: #0 H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\public\index.php(36): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in H:\xampp\htdocs\schedule.dev\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Comment: Try `composer dumpautoload`, then run it again.

Comment: it doesn't help:(

Comment: Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php) . Hope it helps