# Nginx error log is not refreshing after run composer update

Tags: laravel, nginx, error-handling, ubuntu-16.04

I am running a OS Ubunutu 16.4.2 with Nginx as a server.
After clone a laravel project, and run `composer install` and `npm install` and create the `.env` file and run `sudo chown -R ila:www-data mysite.com/`.

That was the error I got from NginX error log with a 404 in the browser:

```
2017/06/14 15:52:47 [error] 11459#11459: *16 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: 
PHP Warning:  
require(/home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
/home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
'/home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in 
/home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17" while 
reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 
mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
"fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.com"
```

Then following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php) I ran `composer update` and I am still getting the 404 error in the browser and now error log is not being updated `tail  -f /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-error.log`.

So I still get the error 404 in the browser and no clues in the error log.

Any idea in how to solve this scenario?

Note:
I was expecting to have any permission error for the storage/ file that I could solve with `chmod guo+w storage/`.

### Update

I will track the exactly point where or when the logs file stops to be updated.

1. Deleted the project and ran the URL mysite.com. Result an **error 404 Not Found nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)**.
   Got this error in **mysite.com-error.log**

   2017/06/15 09:16:18 [error] 3718#3718: *30 FastCGI sent in stderr: 
   "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: **No such 
   file or directory** in Unknown on line 0
   Unable to open primary script: 
   /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/public/index.php (No such file or 
   directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 
   127.0.0.1, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.com"

   Which is expected since I dont have the project directory.
2. Cloned the repository into vhosts/ and ran the URL mysite.com. Result an error **This page isn’t working mysite.com is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500**

   2017/06/15 09:35:32 [error] 3718#3718: *41 FastCGI sent in stderr: 
   "PHP message: PHP Warning:
   require(/home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): 
   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
   /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
   PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 
   '/home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' 
   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in 
   /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17" while 
   reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 
   mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.com"

   The project is being reached by the server but have an issue with the 
   autoload.php now it is a Laravel issue.
3. Now I will run `composer install` and `npm install`. Now I have **vendor/autoload.php** and nothing inside bootstrap/cache. After run ran the URL mysite.com in the browser I still have **This page isn’t working mysite.com is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500**

   `2017/06/15 10:19:31 [error] 3718#3718: *53 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
   Stack trace:
   0 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
   1 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
   2 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
   3 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(203): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
   4 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(114): Illuminate\Log...`

   `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
   Stack trace:
   0 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
   1 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
   2 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
   3 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(203): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorEx`

   Here at this point we have a permission denied for storage/ folder.
4. This is what we have `drwxrwxr-x   6 ila ila   4096 Jun 15 09:35 storage/` AND now I will run `$sudo chmod -R guo+w storage/` to give write permission to `storage/` folder and now we have `drwxrwxrwx   6 ila ila   4096 Jun 15 09:35 storage/`

At this point `$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-error.log` **is not updating**  `mysite.com-error.log`any more AND I have an error in the browser.

[image]

It is a Laravel error. I know I need to create .env file, but before, lets check what we have inside 
**$ tail -f vhosts/mysite.com/storage/logs/laravel.log**

```
#0 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(165): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->writeManifest(Array)
#1 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(61): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest(Array)
#2 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(549): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load(Array)
#3 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerConfiguredProviders()
#4 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(208): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#5 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(160): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#6 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap()
#7 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 {main}
```

5. Creating .env and refreshing the browser. Gave me **NO ERROR** inside **mysite.com-error.log**.

Had the follow error in the browser:[image]

I got the follow error inside **$ tail -f vhosts/mysite.com/storage/logs/laravel.log**

```
[2017-06-15 14:58:23] local.ERROR: Exception: The bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable. in /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:190
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(165): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->writeManifest(Array)
#1 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(61): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest(Array)
#2 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(549): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load(Array)
#3 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerConfiguredProviders()
#4 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(208): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#5 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(160): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#6 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap()
#7 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /home/ila/vhosts/mysite.com/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 {main}
```

At this point I have no error  (updates) inside **tail  -f /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-error.log** AND I have no error (updates) inside **$ tail -f vhosts/mysite.com/storage/logs/laravel.log** AND now I have 404 not found again:[image]

Finally I found my stupid error was inside my routes/web.php file.[image]

Comment: Does the file `mysyte.com/vendor/autoload.php` exist? Did running `composer update` give any errors?

Comment: Eh.. 1 more thing.. In your post you mention the vhost: `mysite.com`, your error log shows `mysyte.com` ?

Comment: Hi Robert, that was my typo error. Now is good.

Comment: And what about my first comment?

Comment: I just could test it at work. I ran `composer update` and nothing. The issue here is how or why the log file is not updated after I ran composer update.

Comment: Does `vendor/autoload.php` exist in your vendor dir ?

Comment: I found the error. I just updated.