# Laravel vendor/autoload is missing

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner in laravel, so when I start creating my project using composer create-project laravel/laravel my-project-name 5.4.*

then i run it on my browser http://localhost:8080/test/public/ and it shows me this error:

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public\index.php on line 24

and

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public\index.php on line 24

I've tried using composer install, update etc.. but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php)

Comment: have you edited `public\index.php`?

Comment: how should i know? @noufalcep

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy i haven't

Comment: @JoselParayno `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';` please check if this line is in your `index.php`?

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy yes it is on line 38 on my index.php

Comment: @noufalcep i've tried enabling openssl before i create the project, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is probably an authorization problem, change your folder or user permissions and try to install laravel again.

Comment: @Onix what do you mean by change your folder?

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload `

Comment: @AnarBayramov i tried this one too, but nothing happens.

Comment: @AnarBayramov composer dump-autoload gives me error like this. Class Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-autoload-dump script
> php artisan package:discover

Comment: try `composer global update`

Comment: @AnarBayramov  i encounter error C:\xampp\htdocs\test>composer global update
Changed current directory to C:/Users/TIP-QC/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Users\TIP-QC\AppData\Roaming\Composer
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: maybe your "vendor" folder is missing..

Answer (score 4):

You'll solve your problem with running in the terminal inside your project

```
composer update
```

Comment: Did you do this after cd-ing to the project? Also, when you say it didn't do anything, do you mean the function didn't run?

Comment: This is the output after i run composer update: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 61 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.3.8): Downloading (100%)

Comment: @GoogleMac yes i did cd-ed on my root project.

Comment: Your index.php page should require the autoload file. Not sure why this isn't already set up on a fresh project. The folder appears to be there, it just isn't being pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'composer diagnose'.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\test>composer global diagnose
Changed current directory to C:/Users/TIP-QC/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BAA 7E54SC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  877195A6 8F3BB743 4E5D42D0 82A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 220C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE51952