# error warring message for require dir

Tags: php, laravel

Why am I getting this warning message when I try to go on my website?

```
Warning: require(/home1/mylist/public_html/alllocal../..vendor.autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/mylist/public_html/alllocal/index.php on line 24
```

Here is my index.php page

```
require __DIR__.'/../alllocal/vendor/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../alllocal/bootstrap/app.php';
```

can someone please help me solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You may need to run `composer install` to build the `autoload.php` file.

Comment: I did that and it tells me that there is nothing to  install or update

Comment: should i delete it and then composer install to have it build the autoload.php

Comment: You can try `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Also try `composer update --no-scripts` [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36395204/3585500). Many other suggestions on that link as well.

Comment: @StephanyRocks Why, did you change your `/public/index.php`, (you shouldn't)? And what is your webserver?  Your server config should point to this file as document root...

Comment: @Bart  I'm using a shared hosting site thats why it says public_html

Comment: @ourmandave it dosen't do  anything

Comment: @Sarcastron that doesn't do anything

Comment: @StephanyRocks Laravel doesn't work fine in subdirectories. It is a whole app ecosystem with composer and lots of other things going on...

Comment: @StephanyRocks Although you can finally set it working (with different tweeks), you will definitely hit other problems in future. Therefore, try to build/develop upon examples in laravel docs...

Comment: @StephanyRocks which shared hosting are you using?