# autoload.php missing when its there

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, autoload

I have started a new Laravel Project and wanted to test it on my localhost...
When I view the site I get an error message saying:

> Warning:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\public/../Website/vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\public\index.php on line 24 Fatal Error:
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\public/../Website/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\public\index.php on line 24

I looked it up, but I found the autoload.php file in all folders and I already tried `composer update --no-scrips`. I just don't get why it isn't loading the project.

'Website' is the name of my Laravel project folder btw.

Comment: What is your DIR structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php)

Comment: Try deleting `composer.lock` file and then do `update composer` and then try again.

Comment: `index.php` is under `Website\public\index.php` but you're looking for autoload under `public/../Website/vendor/autoload.php` which translates to `Website/Website/vendor/autoload.php` which looks wrong.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Just tried it, but didn't help :/

Comment: @apokryfos How did that happen?

Comment: It would happen if you modified your `index.php` . [the original one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php#L24) does `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'` which is the correct path. Compare what you have to the source code one and see if everything looks correct

Comment: @apokryfos Hmm, that's strange. I didn't edit my index.php, but thanks for the answer I try to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem thanks to apokryfos.
In the autoload file the **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php' was changed to **DIR**.'/../Website/vendor/autoload.php' which was the wrong path. I don't know how this could happen, but simply deleting the 'Website/' seemed to fix the problem.
Thanks again to apokryfos.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't enable openssl in my php.ini so when I created my new project with composer it was installed from source. I changed that and ran

```
composer update
```

now the vendor folder was created