# Laravel and phpunit - can't reach tests

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm starting with tests in Laravel and 
now i can't reach my tests using phpunit.

The version of Laravel i'm using is 5.0.

OS is centos7 with php 5.6.

So, the first code i wrote is a duplicate of a existent function in the ExampleTest.php file, stored into "tests" folder, like this:

```html
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

 /**
  * A basic functional test example.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function testBasicExample()
 {
  //1 - verificando se a home devolve codigo 200
  $response = $this->call('GET', '/');
  $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
 }

 public function testBasicExample2()
 {
  //1 - verificando se a home devolve codigo 200
  $response = $this->call('GET', '/');
  $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
 }


}
```

This code is only for learning purposes and the goal here is make phpunit run both functions testBasicExample and testBasicExample2.

Te next step is running phpunit. In my case, i had to go to the vendor/phpunit directory and run command "php phpunit".
Then, the command returned an error: [Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php)

So, i followed the best answer and i run "composer update" into terminal.

Ok, now i can run "php phpunit", but it run other tests and i can't see my exampletest return.

[image]

If some more data is needed, please just ask.
Any help is apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the binary from your project root:

```
cd /path/to/project/root
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

This should automatically pick up the laravel included `phpunit.xml` configuration. If it does not work you can try running it as :

```
cd /path/to/project/root
./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration /path/to/project/root/phpunit.xml
```